# error: make directory //FacebookSDK.framework: Permission denied

Tags: xcode, permissions

I'm having an issue with xcode. I'm trying to complique my iPhone app, but it now seems I can't do so anymore.

I always get this error:

> make directory //FacebookSDK.framework: Permission denied

I have changed my folder permissions to drwxrwxrwx. Doesn't seems to work, I also have tried to change the Derived data folder location. No luck here,

So could you pleas guys give me a hand on this one.

Thank you, regards

Morgan 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

build Phases===>Embed Frameworks ====>select the destination to Frameworks,then everything is fine.